# How does tag synonyms work?

Tags: support, tagging, tag-management

The tagging system has an option for suggesting a synonym, which is sort of a "soft merge" between two tags. It turns everything in one tag, to be named as another tag.

Is there some [semi-]official guide as to how synonyms work? More specifically, how do I know which tag is going to be swallowed into the other?

Comment: It's not really a soft merge, the old tag (now the synonym) still exists. But when you search for it or when you try to add it to a new question, the target tag will be used instead. When moderators create a synonym, they have the choice to do a real merge at the same time.

Comment: To add: moderators can, at any time, approve a pending synonym suggestion, merge a slave synonym into its master, or delete a synonym altogether. (The last is more useful when two tags are made synonyms but not merged.)

Answer (score 3):

> More specifically, how do I know which tag is going to be swallowed into the other?

According to [Tag synonyms: which is the master one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199238/tag-synonyms-which-is-the-master-one) at meta.SE, if you suggest a synonym on the page of some tag, it will become master.

For example, if you suggest a synonym in [this dialog](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebra-precalculus/synonyms), then [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) will be the master tag.

[image]

---

Another useful link about tag-synonyms if the faq post: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Comment: In my opinion, the choice of master tag makes sense, since you need at least a few upvotes in the tag, if you want suggest a synonym. So it is more probable that you will be suggesting a synonym on the page of the tag which has more questions (more chance to receive upvotes); and tag with more questions is also more probable to be the master.